# Define Moment.js locale without overriding the current locale

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Is it possible to include another locale in moment.js (specifically 2.10.3+) without setting it to be the default at the same time?

For example, if I load the minified version of moment.js on to the page and then load a locale (say) https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/2.24.0/src/locale/fr.js the default locale for the entire page becomes french unless explicitly set otherwise.

It seems from my testing that both `.locale()` and `.defineLocale()` set the ***global default locale*** rather then add the definition for use later